# How to match the format “Sep-14” for converting it to DATETIME

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I am trying to transform the column, 'issue_d' by year.

below is the code I have used but it gives me error

```
dt_series = pd.to_datetime(df['issue_d'], format= '%m-%Y')
df['year'] = dt_series.dt.year
```

this is the error message

```
ValueError: time data 'Sep-14' does not match format '%m-%Y' (match)
```

Comment: How is df['issue_i'] data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error, I am pretty sure that `df['issue_d] = 'Sep-14'`. That means that you are using the wrong format string. The format string you have specified expects the months as digits and the full year (4 digits), i.e., `'09-2014'`

What you want as a format string is `'%b-%y'` which takes the abbriviated month name in your locale and the year as two digits (starting at 2000). Thus, your line should look like

```
dt_series = pd.to_datetime(df['issue_d'], format= '%b-%y')
```

The different formats can be found in the Python `datetime` documentation, found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).